# Why are my django locales failing this way?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a website that will be in both french and english, but my Django locales are not really working: on my machine, it works fine (with `./manage.py runserver`)

[image: The site as rendered by the latest Google Chrome on the latest MacOS while the server is on my machine]

but when I send the code on my server, for deployment ...

[image: The site as rendered by the same Google Chrome and the same MacOS, but while on my server]

This is the page's code :
Template

```
<head>
    <!-- Removed meta and useless stuff for clarity -->
    {% load i18n %}
    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <!-- LANGUAGE_CODE is always 'en-us' on prod -->
    <!-- Which is the default in settings.py -->
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}

    {% language fav_lang %}
    <!-- But this is empty on prod, while it is 'en' on my machine -->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Same here, removed CSS stuff and pretty spacing -->

    BetaGames
    <br>
    {% trans "message" %}
    <br>
    {{ fav_lang }}
</body>

{% endlanguage %}
```

And view:

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template("index.html")
    context = {
        'fav_lang': request.LANGUAGE_CODE,
    }
    #So yeah, request.LANGUAGE_CODE is empty on prod
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I pretty much figured from there that this is certainly my server config breaking things. But my server's `settings.py` and my local test are the same:

```
import os

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Just removed debug/hosts/secret key there

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',    #locale should be between sessions and common
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'BetaGames.urls'    #Just have / pointing to the "website in construction" view

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',    #Needed here, think the docs said that
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BetaGames.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),    #Nothing in the DB yet, so this is default stuff
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
    ]

USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/spectre/docs/dist'),    #CSS stuff
]

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', ugettext_lazy('French')),
    ('en', ugettext_lazy('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

I have .po files and compiled them to .mo and I know traduction works, because it does when I change the lang by hand with LANGUAGE_CODE in settings.py ...

So I don't really know where this comes from, I'd be happy I anyone could shine some light on that.

PS: I know that since LANGUAGE_CODE is not set, it will default to en-us, but this is what I want: the website being in english, unless someone with a french web browser comes by.

Comment: are the locales that are installed on your server the same as the locales that you have on your development machine?

Comment: @matyas yes, both locale/fr and locale/en are on the repo, and were compiled on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking a bit, I got something that works, but not how I wanted it to:

I changed the `MIDDLEWARE` var to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py, and I added i18n patterns to my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

import pages

urlpatterns = []

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', pages.views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

So now i can access the french translated site with `domain.com/fr/app` and `domain.com` redirects to `domain.com/en`.

However, this is not really what I wanted, since I hoped to be able to make all of that work without touching the url.

If anyone knows a way to do that, I'll take it, but I'll roll with that for now.